# ASP.NET Mvc Dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, drop-down-menu

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#musteri_sno").change(function () {
        var strSayacID = "";
        strSayacID = $(this)[0].value; // get the selected state id

        var url = "/SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strSayacID ;
        // call controller's action
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            // do something once the data is retrieved
            $("#sayac_no").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                $("#sayac_no").append("<option value='"
                 + optionData.sno
                 + "'>" + optionData.sayac_seri_no
                 + "</option>");
            });
        });
    })
.change(); // making sure the event runs on initialization for default value
});
```

html

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("musteri_sno", (SelectList)ViewBag.musteri_id, "--Müşteri Seçiniz--", new { id = "musteri_sno" })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("sayac_no", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Sayaç Seçiniz --", new { id = "sayac_no" })
</td>
```

action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MusteriSayaclariniGetir(int musteri_sno)
{
    var sites = entity.TblSayaclar.Where(x => x.musteri_id == musteri_sno).Select(x => new { sno = x.sno, sayac_seri_no = x.seri_no });
    return Json(sites, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I removed parameter musteri_no from `MusteriSayaclariniGetir(int musteri_sno)` action, my codes work correctly.  Is there a problem with url `var url = "/SayacOkumalari/MusteriSayaclariniGetir/" + strStateID;` or different error?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide your routes? Also what kind of error du you recieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of your routing. Use "id" instead of "musteri_sno" to use the default map or add one more routing map for your controller in Global.asax.cs